# admob plus and ionic results in runtime error (plugin.constructor.getPluginRef is not a function)

Tags: ionic-framework, admob

I'm trying to implement ionic admob plus in my ionic application. But whenever I try to show the ad I get the following error. This error appears both for a banner as an interstitial ad.

```
    
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: plugin.constructor.getPluginRef is not a function
    TypeError: plugin.constructor.getPluginRef is not a function
        at checkAvailability (VM2270 vendor.js:50324)
        at callCordovaPlugin (VM2270 vendor.js:50417)
        at VM2270 vendor.js:50251
        at VM2270 vendor.js:50193
        at new t (VM2269 polyfills.js:3)
        at tryNativePromise (VM2270 vendor.js:50192)
        at getPromise (VM2270 vendor.js:50213)
        at wrapOtherPromise (VM2270 vendor.js:50250)
        at VM2270 vendor.js:50509
        at cordova (VM2270 vendor.js:148098)
        at c (VM2269 polyfills.js:3)
        at new t (VM2269 polyfills.js:3)
        at tryNativePromise (VM2270 vendor.js:50192)
        at getPromise (VM2270 vendor.js:50213)
        at wrapOtherPromise (VM2270 vendor.js:50250)
        at VM2270 vendor.js:50509
        at cordova (VM2270 vendor.js:148098)
        at Banner.show (VM2270 vendor.js:91387)
        at MyApp.webpackJsonp.717.MyApp.showAd (VM2271 main.js:2123)
        at VM2271 main.js:2139
```

My code: for a banner ad:

```
this.adMob.banner.show({
    id: {
        android: "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        ios: ""
    }
});
```

My code: for an interstitial ad:

```
this.adMob.interstitial.load({
    id: {
        android: "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx",
        ios: ""
    }
}).then(() => this.adMob.interstitial.show())
```

both android ad keys are correct. 
My package.json:

```
{
    "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^6.2.9",
        "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
        "@ionic-native/admob-plus": "^5.17.0",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.15.1",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^5.15.1",
        "@ionic-native/device": "^5.15.1",
        "@ionic-native/facebook": "^5.15.1",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^5.15.1",
        "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.15.1",
        "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.15.1",
        "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.15.1",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.15.1",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.15.1",
        "@ionic/lab": "^1.0.13",
        "@ionic/pro": "1.0.20",
        "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
        "cordova-admob-plus": "^0.32.0",
        "cordova-android": "7.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^3.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
        "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.6",
        "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^7.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.2.1",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
        "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.3",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.6.0",
        "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
        "ionic-long-press": "^1.5.0",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "ng2-cordova-oauth": "0.0.6",
        "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
        "rxjs": "5.5.2",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.3",
        "core-js": "^2.6.4",
        "typescript": "^3.1.4"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
        "cordova-plugin-file": {},
        "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
            "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "11.8.0"
        },
       "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
            "APP_ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "APP_NAME": "xxxxxx",
            "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "4.38.1"
        },
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
        "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
        "cordova-admob-plus": {
            "APP_ID_ANDROID": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "18.2.0"
        }
    },
    "platforms": [
        "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Does anyone see what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the ionic plugin wrapper is broken and it just won't work. And it seems that it has been like that for a while, so it is not likely that it will be fixed anytime soon.

So, in order to make it work, uninstall everything admob-related:

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-admob-plus
npm uninstall @ionic-native/admob-plus
```

Also remove from your code all the imports, instances and calls to the plugin. Then install just the cordova plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-admob-plus --variable APP_ID_ANDROID=ca-app-pub-xxx~xxx --variable APP_ID_IOS=ca-app-pub-xxx~xxx
```

In the page that you are using admob on, add this before the @Component declaration:

```
declare var admob;
```

This variable will give you access to the plugin. Then you can load the banner like this:

```
admob.setDevMode(true);
admob.banner.show({
    id: {
      ios: 'ca-app-pub-xxx~xxx',
    },
  });
```

You can read more about this issue [here](https://github.com/admob-plus/admob-plus/issues/76)

Comment: this did the trick. I had to fiddle a bit with my google play api versions in my project.properties but that is an unrelated problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that worked for me since the plugin has changed in 2022. I have the `admob-plus-cordova` plugin installed like this:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add admob-plus-cordova --save --variable APP_ID_ANDROID=ca-app-pub-xxxx~yyyy --variable APP_ID_IOS=ca-app-pub-xxxx~yyyy
```

But when I used the `@ionic-native/admob-plus` with this, I also received the above error. I didn't want to use the Cordova plugin directly. So to resolve this, I did this:

```
npm uninstall @ionic-native/admob-plus
npm install @admob-plus/ionic
```

And then changed all reference to `admob-plus` From this:

```
import { AdMob } from '@ionic-native/admob-plus/ngx';
```

To This:

```
import { AdMob } from '@admob-plus/ionic/ngx';
```

That's it. Also make sure you review the code that shows the ad.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the documentation of [admob plus](https://admob-plus.github.io/docs/ionic.html) you should use the package `@admob-plus/ionic` instead of `@ionic-native/admob-plus`.

This plugin is maintained by the same people as the cordova-package.
This should be better than directly working with cordova.